# How do I get the quantity total for each widget grouping

Tags: c#

How do I get the quantity total for each widget grouping?

Expected Result:
WidgetA - Sum of quantity
WidgetB - Sum of quantity
WidgetC - Sum of quantity
WidgetD - Sum of quantity

```
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Widget> list = new();
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetA", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetB", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetC", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetD", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetA", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetB", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetC", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetD", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetA", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetB", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetC", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetD", Quantity = 2 });
            list.Add(new Widget() { WidgetName = "WidgetA", Quantity = 2 });


            var queryResult = (from x in list
                               group x by x.WidgetName into res
                               select new Widget
                               {
                                   WidgetName = res.First().WidgetName,
                               }).ToList();
        }
    }

    class Widget
    {
        public string WidgetName { get; set; } = "";
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

by summing the quantity of all widgets in the res grouping

```
var queryResult = (from x in list
                   group x by x.WidgetName into res
                   select new Widget
                   {
                       WidgetName = res.First().WidgetName,
                       Quantity =  res.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
                   }).ToList();
```